# Adding label to exisiting png picture, using convert

Tags: shell, unix, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I need to add a label onto a png picture, also I need to do a command substitution in order to get a number from a file.

I have something like

```
convert image.png  -background red  label:'input + `grep max numbers.txt | head -n 1 | awk '{print 2}'`' -gravity Center -append
```

but I have a very limited understanding of convert, I downloaded it just so I could do this one command

Thank-you

Comment: Please show the format of `numbers.txt` and explain what you are trying to achieve. You almost certainly do not need `grep` and `head` and `awk` - just `awk` will do it all - whatever it is.

Comment: I figured this out and included it in my [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498671/create-a-captioned-meme-using-python-and-pil)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need something like this:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:red label:"input + $(awk '/max/{print $2; exit}' numbers.txt)" -gravity center -append result.png
```

[image]

You need to put the `label:` part in double (rather than single) quotes for the shell to expand and execute it. You do not need `grep` and `head` and `awk`. Awk alone is capable of finding the first occurrence of `max` and then printing the second field and exiting before finding any other instances.

I assume `numbers.txt` looks something like this:

```
a 34
max 32
max 33
```

Comment: When I tried that I just got convert: delegate library support not built-in '/Library/Fonts//Arial.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1740. a bunch. Also I guess the red part isn't necessary I just included it cause I didn't really understand convert. I basically just want to take a png image and write one word followed by one number.     Also numbers.txt is basically like an html code file. There's no structure that looks like a 34 max 32....... it's just the only time max comes up it's followed by the number which I desire. Does that make sense?

Comment: Seems odd that you would get that message. Please try `convert label:"test" a.png`

Comment: Got this. convert: delegate library support not built-in '/Library/Fonts//Arial.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1740.
convert: delegate library support not built-in '/Library/Fonts//Arial.ttf' (Freetype) @ warning/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1740.
convert: no images defined `a.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235 do that mean it's not installed right or something?

Comment: I don't understand, that looks like instructions on how to download some software, which I tried but got stuck at 

cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/etc/ImageMagick-6 because I didn't have this directory

Comment: Yeah I got this when I tried these instructions

10-228-3-3:.magick Sam$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/etc/ImageMagick-6
-bash: cd: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-1/etc/ImageMagick-6: No such file or directory

I feel like what I'm trying to do is really trivial, I just want to take a text word from a file and print it to a png image

Comment: @C.Monster Ok, the bit where you are stuck is about finding your `type.xml` file to edit. If you can't find it, try this command and it will tell you where it is `convert -debug configure -list font 2>&1 | grep -E "Searching|Loading"`